# What is the most secure method to upload image file to server with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I know this topic is widely talked about. I've done my research, and decided to store image files onto the server instead of the DB as a blob file. The problem that I am having is trying to figure out the best way to upload the file, store it in a designated folder then storing the destination in the db..say../img/something.jpg - I've tried looking through many resources but most of them are missing some important steps in the process.

**Problems:**

1. Finding a secure way for uploading the img file
2. Limiting the file
3. size Uploading the image to a destination file
4. Storing the destination file as a text in the DB

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean with `Finding a secure way for uploading the file` and `Limiting the file?` Do you want to limit it to certain extensions or?..

Comment: Yes. Only limit users to .png or .jpg files.

Comment: I want users to be able to upload an image, say their profile image, but securely. I don't want users to upload executables or anything that pose a threat to my site.

Comment: in fact, the accepted question actually easily allows an executable.

Comment: @diesel I've redone the solution taking the mentioned security aspects in mind. You might want to look over it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, this covers the basic ideas of what you want to do:

```
<?php
    $allowedTypes = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
    $maxSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; // 3Mb

    $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

    // check if there was an error
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        die($_FILES["file"]["error"]);
    }

    // check if the filetype is valid
    if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes))
    {
        die("Invalid file type: $fileType");
    }

    // check if the size doesn't exceed the limitations
    if ($fileSize > $maxSize)
    {
        die("The file was too big: $fileSize");
    }

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmpfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    // check if the filename is valid
    if (preg_match("/[\w-]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/", $name) != 1)
    {
        die("Invalid file name: $name");
    }

    // create unique name if needed

    $path = "/var/www/images/" . $name;

    move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $path);

    // add the filepath to mysql
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("imagedb");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (Location, Size) VALUES ('$path', '$size');");
?>
```

This is meant to show how it could be done.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I said that he'd want to generate a unique filename in the end, but that's up to him anyway. Plus basic idea != most secure file upload ever invented. Thinking about it, move_uploaded_file would probably error out if you used non-allowed characters.. has anyone tried this?

Comment: the question was not "how to upload" but how to make a secure upload. your code fails it anyway. Executables are easily allowed.

Comment: Do you recommend any resouces @Col.Shrapnel?

Comment: these "non-allowed characters" merely a spaces and most filesystems allows them in the filenames. As well as quotes. And, to let you know, one have NOT "thinking" nor "trying" about if SQL security should be applied or not, but it have to be applied explicitly and unconditionally.

Comment: There, added a regex match that should prevent everything except `[A-z_-]` which again should prevent SQL injections.

Comment: @diesel the whole resource is just 4 words: "don't trust user input". `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is coming from the user. Thus, it shouldn't be used in whatever security checks.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel the file comes from the user, you should not trust it. I could hide all kind of crap inside an image.. but that's not the point.

Comment: @luastoned that's another delusion. Never confuse data validation and data sanitization. First one may change (for the some foreign language for example) but second one should remain untouched forever and independent from whatever circumstances. It is surprizing me, why are you so reluctant to use some basic SQL sanitization and constantly inventing some lame excuses why not to use it.

Comment: the file contents is another matter, but I was talking of the file type. which ought to be determined by the file extension

Comment: Yeah the file content is indeed another thing, yet I don't get why you are not accepting my fixed solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help luastoned, I think I was able to get it to work. In terms of security, I'll need to further more test it. I'm trying to store the file size, what would be the most recommended type to do so for MySQL?

Comment: The file size? An INT should be fine if you don't modifly it. If you want to store it in Kb / Mb you'd want to use FLOAT

Answer (score 1):

Dunno what all your points about, but what you really have to be concerned with is

- check for the file extension.
  extract it from the filename and compare with allowed ones.
  also it would be good to check filename to have only one dot, or at least it doesn't have a name like `name.html.jpg`, due to some odd Apache behavior.
- check for the file contents. the best way would be to create a brand new image out of the uploaded one.
- take usual precautions while working with DB.

Comment: The main problem I'm having is..worrying about users being able to upload files that I do not want them to upload.

Comment: Check my solution again, the regex check should prevent any odd files.

Comment: @diesel got an example of such an undesirable content? Anyway, creating a brand new image should be secure enough. it either fails on some unwanted content or will create a file of which content you can say it is image for sure.

Comment: I think checking for the file extension should be enough. I'm not sure what you mean by "creating a brand new image". What I'm worried about is if someone uploads an executable disguised as one of the accepting file types is all.

Comment: @diesel creating a new image means reading the old image, putting it into a new 'container' and saving it. If anything goes wrong there the image is likely to be corrupt.

Comment: Oh I got it! In terms of saving the file size, what would be the best format to save it in..in terms of storing the # in the DB?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel you could at least provide sample code to your bullet points, how is the OP supposed to learn from that?

Answer (score -2):

read [this](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/upload_security.htm)

personally I'd use [imgur](http://api.imgur.com/) which is used here on stackexchange websites

Comment: I'm sort of confused. So what you're trying saying is to upload the file to imgur?

Comment: @diesel that's what i would do, but you are free to do it your way:)

Comment: Call me inexperienced, but I'm not seeing the connection.

Comment: That "article" on about.com is not terrible, it's worse than terrible and it's no wonder that there are misconceptions about PHP being insecure and what not when such stuff is lying around. Also, -1 for not answering the question + providing a terrible resource to learn from.

Comment: Using imgur you may be uploading a file to *a* server, but the question is clearly about uploading to *your own* server.

Comment: @diesel when you upload to imgur, you are not uploading to your site, so you don't have to be concerned about security (Finding a secure way for uploading the img file, limiting the file, size Uploading the image to a destination file)

Comment: @Kris i have just suggested a way to do it

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou I'm trying to upload this using a PHP call, I don't think I'm familiar with the method you're talking about.